# Sorbet: Too many arguments provided for method Proc0#call

Tags: ruby, typechecking, sorbet

I am trying to pass an argument to Proc0#call but Sorbet fails:

```
foo do |data|
  # Do stuff
end


sig { params(block: T.proc.void).void }
def foo(&block)
  x = { foo: :bar }
  block.call(x) 
end
```

When I run Sorbet, I see this error:

> Too many arguments provided for method Proc0#call. Expected: 0, got: 1
> https://srb.help/7004

How do I avoid this using strict mode?

Answer (score 0):

Now I see it! The signature passes the param as `arg0`

```
sig {params(blk: T.proc.params(arg0: Hash).void).void}
```

See: https://sorbet.org/docs/procs

Comment: `arg0` is the default that gets printed out in error messages, but you can actually pick any keyword you'd like, which can help the readability of some blocks. The important part is that the `param` method is called with keyword arguments only, and not positional arguments